# Postgres DROP TABLE using DO DECLARE and EXECUTE

Tags: postgresql, function, execute, drop-table

I'm trying to drop tables returned from a query using EXECUTE. Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_a (id BIGINT);
CREATE TABLE test_b (id BIGINT);

DO
$f$
DECLARE command TEXT;
BEGIN
SELECT INTO command 'SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG($$DROP TABLE $$ || table_name), $$;$$) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name ILIKE $$test%$$';
EXECUTE command;
END;
$f$;
```

The SELECT statement returns "**DROP TABLE test_a; DROP TABLE test_b**", which I'm passing into the declared variable and trying to run using EXECUTE, but to no effect. What am I doing wrong?

PostgreSQL 9.5.18, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

Comment: FYI to assign that text to a variable you can just do `command := 'your text'`, no need for select.

Comment: That command statement is *not* what you expect. Please print it out with a `RAISE NOTICE` to see what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing the string `SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING ...` in that variable, not the result of the SELECT statement.

You can also simplify `ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(..))` to `string_agg()` and it's highly recommended to use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to generate dynamic SQL, to properly deal with identifiers that need quoting.

Use the following:

```
DO
$f$
DECLARE 
  command TEXT;
BEGIN

 SELECT string_agg(format('drop table %I', table_name), ';')
   INTO command
 FROM information_schema.tables 
 WHERE table_name ILIKE 'test%';

 execute command;
END;
$f$;
```